# Get information from JIRA account with authentification

Tags: vba, excel, jira

Please can anyone help me, I am stuck, I have to extract data from JIRA web page and put it into EXCEL without using plugins that's way i am trying to do it with VBA but I don't how to proceed. I have tried several methods but it dosen't work for me, Is there anyone who has done that already ?

Thank you

Comment: Is this from a filter?

Comment: What about copy paste, You can mimic then what you've done by recording a Mcro to VBA

Answer (score 0):

This is under the assumption you need to gather filter data

```
 (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://linktoyourjira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/yourFilterID/SearchRequest-yourFilterID.xls?tempMax=5000&os_username=yourlogin&os_password=yourpassword","C:\Users\dzcoats\Desktop\Process A $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).xls")
```

While this is a POWERSHELL Script, it will dump your filter results into an excel file.

Things you need to know -

- "linktoyourjira" should be pretty self explanatory, but however its the link to your jira instance
- YourfilterID is the ID for the filter you want to gather data from. If you need to know how to get your filter ID, just google. You need admin access to view the list of filters though (but the filter ID can be found by hovering over and option in the cogwheel next to the filter in the list with the admin page).
- yourlogin & yourpassword should also be pretty self explanatory.
- To run this, just search for powershell in the start menu ( i am assuming you have a microsoft box thats current, as its generally installed everywhere) open it, paste in the editor and hit run :)

Comment: please for login and password i don't need to put quotes "" ? os_username=yourlogin&os_password=yourpassword,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, here is my code :

```
Private JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Private JiraAuth As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Sub JIRA()

  With JiraAuth
       .Open "POST", "https://jiralink/rest/auth/1/session", False
       .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
       .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
       .send " {""username"" : """username""", ""password"" : """password"""}"""
       MsgBox .Status
       If .Status = "200" Then
           sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sErg, 42, 32) & "; Path=/" & sPfad
           Login = True
       End If
  End With

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://jiralink/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/temp/SearchRequest.html?jqlQuery=project+%3D+NAME+AND+Sprint+%3D+1+ORDER+BY+priority+DESC%2C+updated+DESC&tempMax=1000" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

I want to export information to Excel, to get this result : 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReBI2.png)